# How to properly display a menuitem?

Tags: java, android, menuitem

I'm trying to create some MenuItems, this way:

**main_activity_actions.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/item_add"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_add"
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        android:title="@string/action_add"
        android:showAsAction="always" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/item_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="2"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        android:showAsAction="never" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/item_about"
        android:orderInCategory="3"
        android:title="@string/action_about"
        android:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_activity_actions, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

I cannot get the render of those items on the top menu bar. How do I to make this work, please ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: are you using any library for actionbar?

Comment: If you use ActionBarActivity from android support library, with your code here, the menu will be shown automatically on the top menu bar.

Comment: Does your Activity extend ActionBarActivity?

Comment: @CChi, I've extended `ActionBarActivity`, but I wasn't able to display the MenuItems using this code.

Comment: @joao2fast4u, yes, it does.

Comment: @user3797031 and you do not encounter any error?

Comment: What is the theme you have added to your `Activity` in your Manifest file?

Comment: @CChi, nope, I do not.

Comment: @joao2fast4u, the default one, `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. With android support library v7 appcompat, you have to use a specific namespace to use the attribute `showAsAction` correctly. Here is what you need to do on your xml file:

Add your custom namespace declaration to the file like this:

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

Then instead of using `android:showAsAction`, use `app:showAsAction`.

This will allow the menu items to show.

Here's the result file code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/item_add"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_add"
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        android:title="@string/action_add"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/item_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="2"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/item_about"
        android:orderInCategory="3"
        android:title="@string/action_about"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

Hope I have helped you.